# Can I be prompted for file name in Talend Open Studio standalone job?

Tags: talend

I created a job using Talend Open Studio. It uses a context variable of type `File` and prompt is checked.

When I run it from within TOS, I am prompted for the file name and can use the file explorer to chose a file.

But, when I build a standalone job, running the .bat file does not trigger a prompt.

Is it possible to get prompted for a file name in standalone job ? If so, how ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The context variables prompt only works in the studio. If you want to be prompted for a value when you run your job from the shell, you need to use `tMsgBox` at the beginning of your job, like so:
[image]

Choose the "Question" type, and type the question to be displayed at the prompt.

[image]

You can then get the user input from the global variable `tMsgBox_1_RESULT` (and assign it to your context.File variable).

[image]